# 3 way partitioning by an external element

Tags: algorithm, partitioning

There is a 3-way partitioning algorithm designed by Bentley-Mcilroy, which runs somewhat like this (partitioning on basis of the first element. Initially `i = p = 0` and `j = q = n-1`):

```
Scan i from left to right so long as a[i] < a[lo].
Scan j from right to left so long as a[j] > a[lo].
Exchange a[i] with a[j].
If a[i] == a[lo], exchange a[i] with a[p] and increment p.
If a[j] == a[lo], exchange a[j] with a[q] and decrement q.
```

This continues as long as `i <= j`. Once this breaks,

```
Scan j and p from right to left and exchange a[j] with a[p].
Scan i and q from left to right and exchange a[i] with a[q].
```

Now I want to modify it so that instead of partitioning it about the first element, I can partition it based on any external element, say an integer `pivot` (it may be that `pivot` is same as one of the elements in the array, may be the first one too!). How can I do this? I tried doing it by setting `p` to -1 instead of 0, not working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to replace all references to `a[lo]` with `pivot`.

Comment: But then what about the `p`? It is essential to increase `p` whenever `a[i] = a[0]`. That way, after the loop breaks, by simultaneously decreasing q and j, as well as increasing p and i, does it complete the partitioning.

Comment: I didn't tell you to remove the incrementing of p. I just told you to replace a[0] with pivot, so that line would read "If a[i] == pivot, exchange a[i] with a[p] and increment p."

Comment: But then what about the actual value that was stored in `a[0]`?

Comment: It should go to its proper place on the first iteration, when `i` is 0 (you did say you were starting your loop from 0, right?).

Comment: Wait a minute, so you mean to say that in the 3rd and 4th lines, it should be `If a[i] == a[lo]`, else everything should remain same?

Comment: Well, it's currently `If a[i] == a[lo]`, I'm saying that it should be `If a[i] == pivot`. Also, on the first and second lines, `a[i] < a[lo]` should be a[i] < pivot. Just replace "a[lo]" by "pivot" on the whole thing and you should be fine.

Comment: Yeah yeah, that's what I meant in the question, I pasted it and forgot to replace `a[0]` by `pivot`!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17624/discussion-between-ffao-and-cupidvogel)